# Tomcat 8 Db2 Error: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.eo: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=M25044

Tags: db2, tomcat8

I have been trying to resolve this error which was working for so long
out of nowhere we have started facing this issue.

My application, which is a plain Java web application (Jsp/Servlets and couple of utilities and control classes) running on Tomcat 8

One of the functionality is, the user keys in an id which is a key for a DB query to fire up the Database and get the results
In doing so I get this below error, which is more or less a symptom of user not having the privilege to execute the query on the
Db2 Database table.

When I am trying out the same query from any kind of Db2 Client tools or SQL prompt, I don't get this error at all:

> " com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.eo: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, SQLERRMC=M25044"

Comment: Have you checked all the scenarios mentioned in the error message? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic2.html#sql0551n  Do you know the exact statement/command that gets the error code? Have you tried a JDBC trace? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvjcdig.html    have you (can you?) asked IBM Support?

Comment: Check the schema name. you may have two tables on different schema

Answer (score -1):

SQLCODE -551 means that the User executing the Query does not have the right Privilege. So find out which User is running the Query and grant the Privilege to that User. May be from other SQL Clients you use a different User.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but that's exactly I did, before posting my question here, if you read through my question...